# How to add new (and different) values into each jsonb array element using another table (Postgres 12)

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have two tables, one of them(tableA) contains values that needs to be inserted into jsonb column from tableB. So i need to check if tableB.id=tableA.id and tableB.jsoncol(somehow get itemId) = tableA.item_id and if those a equal - insert into selected element of array val1 and val2. json array can be of different length, but always will have item with id = -1. I would appreciate any help.
Here is [dbtable with created tables](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a8fde8e8d1584467c08986262942a865)

TableA:

[image]

TableB:
[image]

Result should look like this (new values should be at the end of json element, not at the beginning, if possible):
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the data sample as text not as images?

Comment: @JimJones hi! i gave a link to the dbfiddle (with already created tables) in description

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Can you try this? `UPDATE tableB SET json_col = json_col || q.x
FROM (
  SELECT id, jsonb_agg(row_to_json(tableA.*))
  FROM tableA 
  GROUP BY id ORDER BY id) q(id,x)
WHERE q.id = tableB.id;`

Comment: @JimJones you can actually do it youself, dbfiddle it editable. your query works, but a bit inconsistent, not all elements was updated, not a single element with id = -1 was updated, and also it added 3 fields (val1,val2,id) instead of 2 (val1,val2). Thanks for the help

Comment: I see now that my answer is also incomplete.. as you need to update the array elements, not only add new ones. I'll delete it